# Vue mixin properties in template showing as undefined in WebStorm IDE?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, webstorm

I've recently refactored some shared code into a mixin in my Vue application.

The code works fine, but WebStorm is showing all the methods as undefined where they're used in the component template (aside from in template literals `{{ }}`).  I therefore no longer have the functionality to <kbd>Cmd + B</kbd> to travel to where the function is defined which is annoying.

See example here:-

```
      <template v-if="(userIsGuest) && suggestedCars.length > 0">
        <div>
          Suggested cars
          <div class="suggested-icon">{{ suggestedCars.length }}</div>
        </div>
```

In the example above, `userIsGuest` and `suggestedCars` are both computed properties.  The properties inside the `v-if` are both showing as undefined in my editor, but the same property inside my template literal `{{ suggestedCars.length }}` shows as defined.

Both are defined in my mixin like so:-

```
export default {
  computed: {
    userIsGuest() {
      return stuff;
    },
    suggestedCars() {
      return stuff;
    },
  }
}
```

When I add `this.` infront of both undefined properties inside my `v-if` they show as defined, but I didn't think I needed `this.` in Vue templates?

Either way - both ways work, so which is correct here?

Comment: works fine for me in the most recent WebStorm version (2021.3.2). What IDE build do you use?

Comment: Hm, I'm on 2021.2.3 - didn't realise I was that far behind - I'll try updating..

Comment: That didn't do it @lena.  Assume you're using Vue 3?  This project is Vue 2.6.11.

Comment: Seems to be a known issue - https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-49915

Comment: tested with Vue2; please share a full code snippet the issue can be reproduced with